# How to create a photo by repeating several photos like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, software-recommendation

[image]

I don't have any knowledge in photoshop or graphic designing. Can I learn to make images like this? Or is there a website/software to help me do this?

Comment: Why would you believe you are unable to learn this?

Comment: This isn't quite the same as a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks computer-generated to me. Try one of the following sites or google 'photo created of photos generator'.

[Mosaically](http://mosaically.com/)
[Easy Moza](http://www.easymoza.com/)

If you still want to do it by hand, you will have to tediously arrange the small images on layers above your background/main image ..

Comment: Please be advised this is a link only answer and while it may answer the OP's question if the links go down we'll remove your answer.  Answers should be able to exist without relying on external sources.